# how to get "alt" of ImageTag from HTML use Htmlparser

Tags: image, tags, html-parsing, alt

As title，I want to get the text of "alt" ,but hava no method in ImageTag of Htmlparser,who can help me, thanks.

Comment: If you can use Javascript then use `document.write(document.getElementById("ImageID").alt);`. Find a good example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_alt)

Comment: thank you,this is indeed a good idea.but my work is get some tags from a web page by use java and Htmlparser,so I can't alter the original page.

Comment: If you use Java... Can you try using the `HtmlInputText` class... It has a `getAlt()` method as well... You can get more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html). Let us know if you try it...

Comment: thank you all the same!
I found a nice jar that is htmllexer.jar. It has a class that is named "Node",So I could get what I want.
if(node instanceof ImageTag) 
{ String value = ((ImageTag)(node)).getAttribute("alt"); 
} 
the node is a instance variable of Node.

Comment: Oh ok... This seems a good option as well... Let me check it out...

Answer (score 1):

With jquery, you can use:

```
var TextAlt = $('img').attr('alt');
```

With Java:

```
for(Element imgElement : img) {
  String imgAlt = imgElement("alt");
}
```

Comment: thank you,but now I just use java and htmlparser to get the informations from imageTag, because I can't alter the original html page,what should I do?

Comment: if(node instanceof ImageTag)
{
  String value = ((ImageTag)(node)).getAttribute("alt");
}

Comment: And the "node" is a instantiation of Node from htmllexer.jar